# How do I create a multi-dimensional object with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= details.length; i++){
    temp.push({"name": details[i].name, "value": details[i].value});
}
```

Which results in an object like this:

```
[{"name":abc,"value":1},{"name":abc,"value":2},{"name":abc,"value":3},{"name":bcd,"value":4}]
```

But my data has some duplicated names. I'd like my result to be:

```
[{"abc": [{"name": "abc", "value": 1}, {"name": "abc", "value":2}, {"name": "abc", "value":3}],}, "bcd
```

and so on. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: could you provide an example of data in details.

Comment: that code is not valid.  `temp.push{ .. }?`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
var temp = new Object();
for (var i=0; i<=details.length;i++){
    if(temp[details[i].name] === undefined){
        temp[details[i].name] = new Array();
    }
    temp[details[i].name].push({"name":details[i].name,"value":details[i].value});
}
```

Here a jsfiddle to test it out a bit : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge2014/qryy14za/

In javascript you need to create a push method in an object to use it the way you did. It only works for the arrays.

Comment: this won't work, because you overwrite the same named index multiple time with new values.

Comment: TYPO: `details.lenght` should be `details.length`

Comment: please give me the details  initial array. I can fix it but without details I'm working blind

Answer (score 0):

**Re-edited:**

There's a lot of redundant information in your json structure.

Here's what I propose for json structure:

```
var jsondata = [
       { 
         "name" : "abc",
         "values" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] 
       },
       { 
         "name" : "bdc",
         "values" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] 
       }
    ];
```

**Too read it:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Name is: " + jsondata[i].name);

    for(var j = 0; j < jsondata[i].values.length; j++)
    {
        console.log("For name '" + jsondata[i].name + "', value is: " + jsondata[i].values[j]);
    }
}
```

**Too create it**

```
var output = [];

for (var i=0; i<=details.length; i++){  

   var isFound = false;

   for(var j = 0; j < output.length; j++)
   {
       if (output[j].name == details[i].name)
       {
           output[j].values.push(details[i].value);
           isFound = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   if (isFound == false)
   {
       output.push({ "name" : details[i].name, "values" : [ details[i].value ] });
   }
}
```